# Can I develop a git repo from two or more locations as the same user?

Tags: git, workflow, rsync

I do High-Performance Computing (HPC) and I have recently started using git. I develop my scripts locally, but I would earlier use 'rsync' to sync my scripts to a folder on the HPC clusters. To run a job, I would then access scripts from the said folders on the clusters.

Now that I use git, I wonder if my workflow must always be:

1. develop locally
2. push to my git repo
3. pull changes onto the cluster, and then
4. run the job?

Often while testing it is easier to make small changes on the cluster itself. But in this case, must I create two usernames (just like we access email from various locations) or will I confuse git by using the same username from two different locations?

Additionally, I do not want to use the rsync method anymore as I work on more than one HPC systems. I have begun using git as an attempt to unify my development directory and use it smoothly from multiple locations.

I tried to look for pre-existing solutions but my git vocabulary is not very good to form the best search phrases.

Anyway, thank you for reading this far and I would really appreciate your comments on this matter! :)

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"will I **confuse git** by using the same **username from two different locations**?"*

No.

Answer (score 0):

No, using the same user id and email is no problem for git. Just do your changes directly on target and test it. If all works perfectly, double check by `git diff` to verify your changes before commiting. Then use `git push` to publish your changes to your remote server (e.g. local gitlab instance). If you want to sync your changes to other devices, use `git pull` (or even better: `git fetch` + `git merge`)